# Inline CCS to resize image for mobile in Emails

Tags: html, css, email, pardot

Trying to use an inline CSS for mobile only in Pardot.

I'm using:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .secondimage {width: 50vw !important;}
```

Which seems to work in mobile.  However Pardot wants to have image height and width:

```
<img align="left" alt="alt" border="0" class="secondimage" src="image.jpg" style="float: left; width: 259px; height: 288px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="259">
```

In mobile Outlook the image has a correct ratio, but in Gmail the image is following the height in pixels and squishing it to 50% of the viewport width.  How can I get it to render in the correct ratio everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height:auto` in your media query style.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .secondimage {width: 50vw !important; height:auto !important; }
}
```